# Managing static libraries

Tags: linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I am linking few libs in one by using command

```
lib.exe /out:X.lib X.lib other1.lib other2.lib
```

The result lib becomes much bigger then it was.
When I am linking the result `X.lib` to my exe everything works perfect till I remove `other1.lib` or `other2.lib` from the file system.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why my result lib becomes SO big if still the original `other1.lib` and `other2.lib` are used.
2. How can I let linker to use data from the result `X.lib` and not from original libs?

Update:
this behavior is relevant just for boost libs in  my case